# Create an array of unique ints in a set range

Tags: code-golf, random, array

***Goal:***

Write a piece of code that produces a array containing *all* integer values in a set range in random order (upper and lower bounds included).
Use any language you like, but use as little built-in functions as possible (ie PHP's `array_shuffle` should be avoided)

***Rules:***

- All ints in the range must be used once, and only once
- The range can be negative, or positive
- When using JavaScript: ECMAScript6 features are to be avoided
- If you choose to write a function the `function(params){` and closing `}` needn't be counted. Bonus points for clever argument validation/normalization if you do write a function
- Aliases like `m = Math;` or `Array.prototype.p = [].push;` will be counted, using closures/functions, passing `Math` as an argument will be counted as `<argName>=Math;`

***Benchmark:***

As a starting point or target: here's a snippet that meets all of the criteria apart from the randomness. It's approx. 50 bytes long (depending on `v`'s value). That would be a nice target to hit:

```
for(l=3,a=[v=12],i=v>0?-1:1;(v+=i)!=l+i;)a.push(v)
```

Caveats: if `l` is bigger than `v`, the code fails.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: sorry, first post. Didn't realize language-specific challenges are discouraged. Would expanding the question to the entire ECMAScript family be desirable? Also: Sure, this is code-golf. It's not a question of _"how should I write this?"_ :-)

Comment: @MartinBüttner: Done.

Comment: Why the hate against ecmascript? With other languages allowed, Javascript won't win anyway.

Comment: Rules 3,4,5 don't make sense.

Comment: @edc65: Those rules stem from the initial question, which was JavaScript specific. I edited that part out, because it was pointed out that language-specific questions are discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### APL, 18

```
{(⍺⌊⍵)-1-?⍨1+|⍺-⍵}
```

Takes upper/lower bounds as left/right argument. Works for any bounds, also reversed bounds.
Can be shortened to 13 characters if the assumption l<=u can be made:

```
{⍺-1-?⍨⍵-⍺-1}
```

[Try](http://tryapl.org/)

Answer (score 0):

### GolfScript (26 bytes)

```
~)1$-:x,\{+}+%{;x.*rand}$`
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyctNyAtNCcKCn4pMSQtOngsXHsrfSslezt4LipyYW5kfSRg)

Could be slightly shorter but at the cost of worse randomisation. By picking random numbers up to the square of the size of the range I come close enough IMO to avoiding collisions.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript, 73 bytes

```
for(i=l,s=[];i<=u;)s[i-l]=i++;s.sort(function(){return Math.random()<.5})
```

Assumes `l` and `u` have the lower and upper bounds resp. and `l<=u`

Answer (score 0):

### CJam, 12 (or 10) bytes

Aannnd, if other languages are allowed, here is an answer in CJam

```
{$~1$-),f+mr`}:F;
```

This creates a function `F` , thus not counting the `{` and `}:F;`.

Example Usage:

```
{$~1$-),f+mr`}:F;
[7 -2]F
```

Output:

```
[1 -2 6 2 -1 5 7 0 3 4]
```

If I assume that first integer is always less than the second integer, then the code comes down to **10 bytes**:

```
{1$-),f+mr`}:F;
```

Example usage:

```
{1$-),f+mr`}:F;
-2 7F
```

Output:

```
[1 -2 6 2 -1 5 7 0 3 4]
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 0):

### PYTHON, 21

`list(set(range(l,u+1)))`

- assumes `l <= u`

I believe `set` uses the hash value of the arguments for the order of this list it generates. This generates kind-of random ordering, for example with `l, u = 30, 50`, I get `[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 30, 31]`. I'd say this still counts though.

Answer (score 0):

### J (11 (or 9))

```
f=:>.-?~@>:@|@-
```

This defines a dyadic function, the arguments of which define the start and end of the range. The order of the arguments doesn't matter. (Does this give me bonus points?)

As per the rules, I'm not counting `f=:` as this is part of the function definition (i.e., what would be `function f(params){`...`}`. An anonymous function would be `(>.-?~@>:@|@-)`, where the `()` can be disregarded according to that rule.

If I can assume the *left* argument to be the *upper* bound, and the *right* argument to be the *lower* bound, it can be shortened to **9**:

```
g=:[-?~@>:@-
```

Or, as an anonymous function, `([-?~@>:@-)`.

Test:

```
   f=:>.-?~@>:@|@-
   g=:[-?~@>:@-
   _5 f 10
_1 2 0 _2 _5 3 _4 _3 1 9 4 10 5 7 6 8
   2 f 10
2 10 5 3 8 4 9 7 6
   10 f 2
2 9 4 5 6 10 3 7 8
   10 f _5
_3 9 4 3 2 6 _2 1 5 8 7 _1 _4 10 _5 0
   10 g 2
2 3 4 7 9 5 6 10 8
   10 g _5
1 2 7 4 3 _4 5 8 6 9 _1 10 0 _5 _2 _3
```

Comment: `_5` === `-5` ? Also, not sure if that is a valid way of providing input to the program.

Comment: @Optimizer: yes, `_5` is the J representation of `-5`. (That's necessary, because arrays are written as `0 1 2 3`. So `[0,1,-2,3]` would be written as `0 1 _2 3`, whereas `0 1 -2 3` means `(0 1)-(2 3)`, i.e. `_2 _2`.) As for providing input, it's just a function. `a F b` is J for `F(a,b)`. There are more people who have submitted functions, and there are even people who just assume preset variables.

Comment: I agree, but both of the other assumptions add extra bytes to the code, while you take the benefit of having the input already present. For instance, I can assume that both integers are already on stack in my [CJam answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/38474/31414) and get rid of two more bytes making the final answer only 10 bytes.

Comment: @Optimizer: according to the rules, you can define a function, and you don't have to count the function definition boilerplate. I'm not that familiar with CJam, but in Golfscript you can do `{`...`}:f;`, if I'm not mistaken, and you wouldn't have to count the `{}:f;` part. So if CJam works the same way, you could do that and be within the rules.

Comment: Hmm, that rule needs to be more clear that it is for all languages and not just JS.

Answer (score 0):

### Perl - 19

```
sort{rand>.5}$l..$v
```

Assuming `$l` and `$v` are already defined. If you wanted to make it a function:

```
sub random_array {
    sort{rand>.5}$_[0].._$[1]
}
```

You can try it with:

```
perl -E'$,=",";$l=1; $v=15; say sort{rand>.5}$l..$v'
```

or

```
perl -E'say random_array(0,5);sub random_array{sort{rand>.5}$_[0]..$_[1]}'
```